# Azure Mobile Client throwing .Ext error

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I see this has been a problem people have been dealing with for years and supposed to be solved the depreciated versions, but here I am.  Have spent more time than I care to admit on what seems to be a simple issue.

Here is my packages folder

```
<packages>
  <package id="Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie" version="1.0.0.7" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="HockeySDK.Xamarin" version="4.1.4" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="UXDivers.Artina.Shared" version="2.0.52" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="UXDivers.Artina.Shared.Base" version="2.0.52" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="UXDivers.Effects" version="0.6.0" targetFramework="portable-net45+win+wp80+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarintvos10+xamarinwatchos10+xamarinios10" />
  <package id="Xam.Plugin.Connectivity" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="Xamarin.FFImageLoading" version="2.2.9" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Forms" version="2.2.9" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="Xamarin.FFImageLoading.Transformations" version="2.2.9" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.4.247" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
</packages>
```

Here is my Droid MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            // Changing to App's theme since we are OnCreate and we are ready to 
            // "hide" the splash
            base.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
            base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppTheme);

            FormsAppCompatActivity.ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabs;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Initialize Azure Mobile Apps
            CurrentPlatform.Init();

...
}
}
```

and in my Cloud Service I have this

```
public AzureCloudService()
        {
            client = new MobileServiceClient("https://For-me-to-know.com");
        }
```

on the instantiation of new MobileServceClient, i get this error

system.InvalidOperationException: A Microsoft Azure Mobile Services assembly for the current platform was not found. Ensure that the current project references both Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile and the following platform-specific assembly: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.

**EDIT**
@Bruce yes my droid and iOs projects have the mobile client added

[image: Reference list for Droid project]

I also have run the break points and it executes the main activity first before it attempts to intantiate the mobile client above.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `packages.config` it seems that this is from your PCL project.

So if you init the `MobileServiceClient` under your Droid project, you need to make sure you have installed the [Azure Mobile Client SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client/3.1.0) NuGet package for your Droid project as follows:

[image]

Additionally, I noticed that you have added `CurrentPlatform.Init();` in your Droid MainActivity class. I would recommend that you check whether the `CurrentPlatform.Init()` call is before you init the `MobileServiceClient` instance.

Comment: I am using version 3.1 just the link you sent.  and Yes CurrentPlatform from a code break standpoint gets called 1st before my service classes get initiated.

Comment: Does IOS work correctly? I recommend you could refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started) for downloading the quick start project to isolate this issue. Additionally, could you provide the Android version and the `packages.config` of your Droid project.